# Active Directory LDAP - Lock User Account

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, active-directory, ldap

What is the best way to use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to lock an Active Directory user object? I'm able to determine if an account is locked using..

```
UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(context);
bool locked = principal.IsAccountLockedOut();
```

How do I lock the account? Is there an alternative to doing something like this...

```
UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(context);
DirectoryEntry entry = (DirectoryEntry)principal.GetUnderlyingObject();

int val = (int)entry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;

entry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = val | 0x0010;
entry.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: See if this helps:
[lock AD user account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422665/251674)

Answer (score 3):

The lock attribute is read-only by definition and here is why:

The definition for this attribute will go something like: "automatically lock user account when invalid password is provided several times" (how many times? I guess this is set in the GPO)

Giving developers a way to change this attribute will conflict with the above definition... so you shouldn't set this value and I think AD security mechanism will block you from doing this.

You can however enable\disable the user which I think is more close to what you want.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

[CodeProject's Everything AD article has some sample code on unlocking an account](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#45). I'm not certain that this is the property that would give you what you're looking for.

```
public void Unlock(string userDn)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry uEntry = new DirectoryEntry(userDn);
        uEntry.Properties["LockOutTime"].Value = 0; //unlock account

        uEntry.CommitChanges(); //may not be needed but adding it anyways

        uEntry.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //DoSomethingWith --> E.Message.ToString();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will work to lock a user in AD

```
        /// 
        /// Locks a user account
        /// 
        /// The name of the user whose account you want to unlock
        /// 
        /// This actually trys to log the user in with a wrong password. 
        /// This in turn will lock the user out
        /// 
        public void LockAccount(string userName)
        {
            DirectoryEntry user = GetUser(userName);
            string path = user.Path;
            string badPassword = "SomeBadPassword";
            int maxLoginAttempts = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxLoginAttempts; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    new DirectoryEntry(path, userName, badPassword).RefreshCache();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            user.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#45

Answer (score 0):

using userflag property we can get the user locked status here is my answer

entryPC is object for the DirectoryEntry here we pass the entry path of active directory

```
 public bool IsLocked(DirectoryEntry entryPC)
    {
        if (entryPC.NativeGuid == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int flags = (int)entryPC.Properties["UserFlags"].Value;
        bool check = Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0010);
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(flags & 0x0010))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```