# Find username from Active Directory using email id

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I am finding user name from Active Directory by passing email id. It is working fine. But it takes 30-40 seconds to get the username. Is there any other better way to find the username from Active Directory by email address?

Please refer to my code:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
{
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(context);
    PrincipalSearcher principalSearch = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);

    foreach (UserPrincipal result in principalSearch.FindAll())
    {
        if (result != null && result.EmailAddress != null && result.EmailAddress.Equals(user.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            user.FirstName = result.GivenName;
            user.LastName = result.Surname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lookup user in ActiveDirectory by email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658345/lookup-user-in-activedirectory-by-email-address)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to enumerate **all** users to find *one* of them! Try this code:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
{
    UserPrincipal yourUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, EmailAddress);

    if (yourUser != null)
    {
        user.FirstName = yourUser.GivenName;
        user.LastName = yourUser.Surname;
    }
}
```

If that shouldn't work, or if you need to search for several criteria at once, used the `PrincipalSearcher` with the QBE (query-by-example) approach - **search** the one user you need - don't cycle through **all** users!

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domainname"))
{    
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(context);
   qbeUser.EmailAddress = yourEmailAddress;

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

Comment: First variant is better, since it works with both username and email - unless you specifically want only email - then use variant 2 (PrincipalSearcher).

Comment: @marc_s when I'm trying same code in .net core it gives below error.         Unable to load DLL 'activeds.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: @PrasadShigwan: you'll need to check out either the [Windows Compatibility Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) or the [Nuget package for AD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/) from Nuget

Comment: for me, the first variant works only with username but not with email. Why?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

// Lock user
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    UserPrincipal yourUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, logonName);
    if (yourUser != null)
    {
        if(!yourUser.IsAccountLockedOut())
        {
            yourUser.Enabled = False;
            yourUser.Save();
        }
    }
}
```