# Find username from email address in active directory vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Sorry, i checked the link "[Find username from Active Directory using email id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801217/find-username-from-active-directory-using-email-id)" but that's for C# i can't figure that out how to do in Vb.net.

In my gridview when i select the row to get the email id and pass it to AD to find the user name but so far i can't figure that out what command will give that details in VB.net

```
Protected Sub grdValidate_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim strEmail As String = grdValidate.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text
    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

    ' find a user
    Dim user As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, strEmail)

End Sub
```

i saw this property "UserPrincipal.EmailAddress" but VS is not even recognize the command. Obviously i imported

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

I am trying to find a command to pass the email and match the email id in AD and get the user information.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any competent VB developer can read C# code, even if they can't write it. There are also plenty of online code converters that can get you at least a good part of the way. Do what you can first and then post if it doesn't work.That C# code contains a `using` statement, and `if` statement and a `foreach` statement, all of which have obvious equivalents in VB.  If you haven't written some code that contains those then you haven't tried and if you haven't tried then it's too soon to be posting here.

Comment: As for the `UserPrincipal` type, just as it does for every other type, the documentation tells you what assembly it's declared in and what namespace it's a member of. Have you referenced and imported those? If not then of course VS won't recognise that type.

Comment: You probably need to add a .NET reference to `System.DirectoryServices`

Comment: And `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .NET references to `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and then...

```
Using context As New System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, strDomainName)
  Dim yourUser As System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, strEmailAddress)
  If yourUser IsNot Nothing Then
    strFirstName = yourUser.GivenName
    strLastName = yourUser.Surname
  End If
End Using
MsgBox(strFirstName & " " & strLastName)
```

I've used fully qualified names for clarity, but you can tidy things up with `Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` at the beginning of the module